# NSIS: adding custom text into status text box

Tags: windows-installer, nsis, status

I have NSIS installer and I need MSI 3.1 to install C++ runtimes.

If installer could not be found or if it is outdated, I show messagebox.
Here is the code:

```
Section "Install"
  GetDLLVersion "$SYSDIR\msi.dll" $R0 $R1  
  ${If} $R0 < 0x00030001 ;require version 3.1 or higher of MSI Installer
    MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK "Windows Installer 3.1 or higher is required. Please install or update your Windows Installer" IDOK "exit"  
  ${EndIf}
```

Label exit is just before SectionEnd.

How to add custom text into NSIS status text box (where the info about files being unpacked is scrolling)? Now there is only "Completed" text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DetailPrint](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.14.3) (You can control where it prints with SetDetailsPrint)